# Order by post confusing

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, sorting

[image]

(On order by posts)

It seems that, in "order by posts", certain posts are being split in two. The entry still shows "4 events", but both of them expand to eight (the *same* eight events). Pretty confusing.

It seems to be gone now, but it wasn't any of my JS magic. I reproed it on an empty(no addons/userscripts) Chrome beta.

I think it's gone now because I got an upvote elsewhere, resetting the page.

Comment: Your question is also very confusing.

Comment: No repro...could it be that you've run into some JavaScript magic? Refresh the site, check again?

Comment: @Kobobby: Hmm, it's gone now. But it was there fve minutes ago and half an hour ago. Lemme see.. No JS magic.

Comment: "I reproed it on an empty Chrome beta"...

Comment: @Nick Oh, sorry. I'm not thinking right today. Empty=no addons/userscripts.

Comment: @Manishearth - that wasn't the point...we don't/won't support beta browsers, [never have](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).

Comment: @Nick I know, but isn't the page generated server-side? The collapsing stuff may be client side, but won't the list itself with associated subcontent? Not sure though, you're the expert :) (I run chrome canary just to have an extra browser. I guess I can switch to the full build on beta)

Comment: @Manishearth - that's not really the point either: there are so many bugs with beta browsers it's not worth our time chasing things down that *aren't our bugs* 90% of the time...it's totally wasted dev effort on these goose chases when we can spend that time fixing things that are actually broken, or adding awesome elsewhere.  Accordingly, we immediately dismiss beta browser bugs the majority of the time, if it was a real issue it'd appear from more people, at least one with a current browser.

Comment: @Nick alright, I'll keep an eye out for it and switch channels on my beta.